# Does the noindex tag prevent bots from crawling the links on the page?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, nofollow, noindex

If I had a page having the noindex tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />`, I know that the page won't be shown on search results.

But will the links on the page still be crawled?

If I want them to be crawled, can I set something like  `<meta name="robots" content="noindex, follow" />`. Will it work?

Comment: follow is the default. You dont need to specify it.

Answer (score 0):

The noindex tag `<meta name="robots" content="noindex" />` is used to prevent most search engine web crawlers from indexing a page on your site.

The crawlers will not index the page using `content="noindex, follow"` tag but will crawl through the rest of the pages.

You can find more details here: http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: I have changed the link. You can check now.